# convert time to unix timestamps since epoch and send it tyo server flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

how can i convert datetime to unix time using datetimepicker package? I need user can choose the date and time and after their choice the chosen date and time convert to unix timestamp and send this timestamp to server.

Now I am trying something like this:

```
var dateUnix = DateTime.now().toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    child: DateTimePicker(
                    type: DateTimePickerType.dateTimeSeparate,
                    dateMask: 'EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss',
                    initialValue: dateUnix 
                    firstDate: DateTime(2000),
                    lastDate: DateTime(2100),
                    icon: Icon(Icons.event),
                    dateLabelText: 'Date',
                    timeLabelText: "Hour",
                    onChanged: (val) => print(val),
                    validator: (val) {
                      print(val);
                      return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (val) => print(val),
```

the output is still:

```
I/flutter (11990): 2022-02-07 12:10
```

I need it aoutomatucally converted to unix-time:

```
Epoch timestamp: 1644235837
```

Comment: I found solution, just needed to write function which converted current chosen datetime to unix time

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in your print statement:

```
print(val.toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString())
```